# use fsolve to return some other variable beside the x vector

Tags: matlab

I have used the `fsolve` function to find the vector `x` ( the answer ) but I need my function to return some other value like `A` but the below code does not work.

This is my function:

```
function [F,A] = myfun(x,c)
    F = [ 2*x(1) - x(2) - exp(c*x(1))
          -x(1) + 2*x(2) - exp(c*x(2))];
.
.
.
    A = 1;
```

this is the caller:

```
[x,a] = fsolve(@(x) myfun(x,c),[-5;-5])
```

but in the above `a` holds the `F(x)` values (which must be nearly zero) instead of `A`.

Answer (score 2):

your last line

```
[x,a] = fsolve(@(x) myfun(x,c),[-5;-5])
```

requests `a` to be the second output of `fsolve` (`fval`). Internally, `fsolve` only uses the *first* output of your function; any other outputs are ignored.

The easiest way to get the second output of your function at the solution point, is to just evaluate the function once more after `fsolve`:

```
x = fsolve(@(x) myfun(x,c),[-5;-5]);
[~,a] = myfun(x,c);
```